# nested for loop in jinja2 template

Tags: python, templates, jinja2

```
{% for key in data %}
{% if 'assignedUser' in key %}
    {% for key_1, value_2 in data[key].items() %}
    <li>Assigned User: data.values_2()</li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I'm trying to make the jinja template behave like this python statement:

```
for key in data:
if key == 'assignedUser':
    for key_1, value_2  in data[key].items():
        print('Assigned User: ' + str(value))
```

'data' object:

```
{
  "assignedUser": {
    "username": "name@email.com"
},
```

Comment: In what way does it not behave correctly?  It looks mostly okay, although inside your innermost `for` loop you're not referencing either `key_1` or `value_2`.

Comment: sorry should be data.value_2

Comment: Can you post a snippet of your 'data' variable?

Comment: {
  "assignedUser": {
    "username": "name@email.com"
  },}

Comment: what is `data.values_2()` ???  You need `{{ value_2 }}`

Comment: BTW: it can be without `{% for key in data %}` - but `{% if 'assignedUser' in data %} {% for key_1, value_2 in data['assignedUser'].items() %}`